# Bitonicsort C code segmentation issue

Tags: c, sorting

I am running a bitonic sort sequential code on a machine. It runs fine for array size upto 16 elements but as soon as i increase the size to 32 It gives the following error while execution:

" WARNING: Process 654 terminated: Segmentation fault (11)."

Can somebody help me whats appening?? Does it occupies alot of memory when the size is increased to 32 Is that why this problem is appearing??

I want to test it to a parallel version. So, i need array size of some considerable length for comparison..

Following is my code:

```
void merge_up(int *arr, int n)
{
int step=n/2,i,j,k,temp;

while (step > 0)
        {

                for (i=0; i < n; i+=step*2)
                {
                        for (j=i,k=0;k < step;j++,k++)
                        {
                                        if (arr[j] > arr[j+step])
                                        { // swap
                                                temp = arr[j];
                                                arr[j]=arr[j+step];
                                                arr[j+step]=temp;
                                        }
                        }
                }
                step /= 2;
        }
}

void merge_down(int *arr, int n)
{

        int step=n/2,i,j,k,temp;
                while (step > 0)
                {
                        for (i=0; i < n; i+=step*2)
                        {
                                for (j=i,k=0;k < step;j++,k++)
                                {       if (arr[j] < arr[j+step])
                                        {       // swap
                                                temp = arr[j];
                                                arr[j]=arr[j+step];
                                                arr[j+step]=temp;
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                        step /= 2;
                }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

int n, i, s;
n = 32;

int arr[32] = {234, 233, 22, 1, 22, 8, 1, 89, 5, 34, 21, 9, 222, 2, 1, 999, 21, 12, 23, 32, 21, 111, 45, 23, 211, 21, 232, 45, 22, 11, 9876, 22, 2, 3, 555, 333};

printArray(arr,n);

// do merges
for (s=2; s <= n; s*=2)
{
        for (i=0; i < n;)
        {
                merge_up((arr+i),s);
                merge_down((arr+i+s),s);
                i += s*2;
        }
}

printArray(arr,n);

}// END 

void printArray(int *arr, int n)
{

        int i;
        printf("[%d",arr[0]);

for (i=1; i < n;i++)
        {
                printf(",%d",arr[i]);
        }
        printf("]\n");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running your code through a debugger?

Comment: also, compiling with `-Wall` gives that you have 36 elemets in your `arr[32]` array. This is generally considered bad.

Comment: `merge_down((arr+i+s),s);` will index beyond the arraysize if  `s == n` (the final iteration)

Answer (score 1):

i think you are overlooking something like

```
warning: excess elements in array initializer
```

your arr is initialized for 32 elements and your are trying to push elements over its limit.

Comment: excess elements in initializer are ignored by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the array out of bounds.

The problem also exists when using size 16. It just doesn't show up because you are creating an array of size 32 even when using size 16.

The illegal access is done here:

`arr[j] > arr[j+step]`

Because `j+step` is too large for the array. Adding a print in your main you easily see what happens:

```
// do merges
for (s=2; s <= n; s*=2)
{
        for (i=0; i < n;) 
        {   
                printf("s: %d, n : %d, i: %d\n", s, n, i); 
                merge_up((arr+i),s);
                merge_down((arr+i+s),s);
                i += s*2;
        }   
}



s: 2, n : 32, i: 0
s: 2, n : 32, i: 4
s: 2, n : 32, i: 8
s: 2, n : 32, i: 12
s: 2, n : 32, i: 16
s: 2, n : 32, i: 20
s: 2, n : 32, i: 24
s: 2, n : 32, i: 28
s: 4, n : 32, i: 0
s: 4, n : 32, i: 8
s: 4, n : 32, i: 16
s: 4, n : 32, i: 24
s: 8, n : 32, i: 0
s: 8, n : 32, i: 16
s: 16, n : 32, i: 0
s: 32, n : 32, i: 0
s: 1857424340, n : 1857424324, i: -580085849
Segmentation fault: 11
```

At some point, `n`, `s`, and `i` change into a random (large) number. This is because when you access the array out of bounds you are changing the memory associated to those variables.

Variables that are local to a function are created on the stack in the order that they are declared. You have

```
int n, i, s;
int arr[32];
```

On your stack this will look something like this

```
stack grows here
 a[0]
 .
 .
 .
 a[31]
 s
 i
 n 
 return address
bottom of the stack frame
```

Meaning if you access `a[32]` or up, you access the variables `n`, `s`, and `i`.

Curiously, if you change the variable declaration to

```
int arr[32];
int n, i, s;
```

The stack will look like this

```
stack grows here
 s
 i
 n 
 a[0]
 .
 .
 .
 a[31]
 return address
bottom of the stack frame
```

And the program works, because the variables on the stack are no longer after the array, but you get a segfault on program exit because you are changing the return address (address that tells the cpu what instruction is next after program termination).

Finally, the problem originates here:

```
merge_up((arr+i),s);
merge_down((arr+i+s),s);
```

At some point `i+s` is 32, and you are calling `merge_down` with an pointer as argument, this pointer points to `arr + 32`, which is already pointing out of bounds. I suggest you change this

Comment: Yes, this is what I commented two hours ago. (why don't people *read* comments ?)

Comment: I didn't see the comment. However after reading it I find your answer a bit incomplete as it doesn't explain why it works with size 16 and not 32. Also, the program doesn't crash on that illegal access, it crashes on the next iteration after the values of `n`, `i` and `s` have been changed illegally.

Comment: Well, it is undefined behaviour, so anything can happen. (probably there is some slack/alignment after the array, or the array itself , and/or  it is overdimensioned, since the OP only varies N, not the array itself)